# es6 module with few lines of code. What should I export?

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, helper

I have a jQuery helper with just a few lines of code:

```
$(document).on('change', '.foo', (e) => {
  $(e.target).closest('form')[0].submit();
});
```

The problem is, I use es6 modules and I don't know what to export. What is the best way to write this?

Should I do:

```
export default function foo() {
  $(document).on('change', '.foo', (e) => {
    $(e.target).closest('form')[0].submit();
  });
}
```

And call foo in every file I need this helper? (I could also put it in my entry file but later it will be harder to know if it's still used by a module).

Or:

```
export default (function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.foo', (e) => {
    $(e.target).closest('form')[0].submit();
  });
})()
```

(but this one seems really ugly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to export anything. If you only want to execute a side effect through loading the module, that's fine.

```
// foo-submitter.js
import $ from 'jquery';
$(document).on('change', '.foo', (e) => {
    $(e.target).closest('form')[0].submit();
});
```

```
// main.js
import 'foo-submitter';
```